# Multiple ListViews sharing a ContextMenu, how can I reference the right object?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, contextmenu

I have many ListViews, each bound to their own ListCollectionView, each with identical ContextMenu needs.  I don't want to repeat the same ContextMenu N times, so I define it in the Resources and refer to it via StaticResource.

When an item X in a ListView is right clicked, and a MenuItem is clicked, how can I access object X in the codebehind?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="CommonContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" Click="DoStuff_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCollectionView1}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CommonContextMenu}">
    ...
</ListView>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCollectionView2}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CommonContextMenu}">
    ...
</ListView>

private void DoStuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // how do i get the selected item of the right listview?
}
```

**Update**

Thanks to Michael Gunter's answer, I am now using the following extension methods:

```
public static ListView GetListView(this MenuItem menuItem)
{
    if (menuItem == null)
        return null;

    var contextMenu = menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (contextMenu == null)
        return null;

    var listViewItem = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as ListViewItem;
    if (listViewItem == null)
        return null;

    return listViewItem.GetListView();
}

public static ListView GetListView(this ListViewItem item)
{
    for (DependencyObject i = item; i != null; i = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(i))
    {
        var listView = i as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
            return listView;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put the context menu on each item within each `ListView`, rather than on each `ListView` itself. This avoids the context menu from popping up when clicking on the empty space in the `ListView`. To do this, use the `ListView.ItemContainerStyle` property. (If you really want the context menu on the `ListView` itself, let me know and I'll edit this answer accordingly.)

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="CommonContextMenu">
        <MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" Click="DoStuff_Click" />
    </ContextMenu>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource CommonContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCollectionView1}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    ...
</ListView>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListCollectionView2}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

2) Use code like the following to determine what item was right-clicked upon.

```
private void DoStuff_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = sender as MenuItem;
    if (menuItem == null)
        return;

    var contextMenu = menuItem.Parent as ContextMenu;
    if (contextMenu == null)
        return;

    var listViewItem = contextMenu.PlacementTarget as ListViewItem;
    if (listViewItem == null)
        return;

    var listView = GetListView(listViewItem);
    if (listView == null)
        return;

    // do stuff here
}

private ListView GetListView(ListViewItem item)
{
    for (DependencyObject i = item; i != null; i = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(i))
    {
        var listView = i as ListView;
        if (listView != null)
            return listView;
    }
    return null;
}
```